# JetBrains dotTrace is not working when trying to do a Profile on local machine

Tags: asp.net, profiling

I'm currently trying to set-up a trace/profile for my ASP.NET application using  JetBrains' dotTrace Performance Profiler.

Whenever I try to start my IIS app, I keep on getting this error:

```
---------------------------
JetBrains Product – dotTrace Performance 5.0
---------------------------
Error - w3wp.exe (11148):
Can't create file (system error 5 - Access is denied.)
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Tried implementing my windows account in IIS and place the appropriate security settings for the application folder that it is trying to profile, but I keep on getting this error.

Was wondering if you guys had encountered this error, and if so, what steps did you do to fix it?

Comment: What OS are you running this on?  Is UAC turned on?  Did you run DotTrace as an administrator?

Comment: I'm running dotTrace on Windows 7 64bit and is running as administrator. Did try to turn off UAC, to no avail.

Comment: 1.  Go Get Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) 2. Run Process Monitor 3.  Start Dot Trace and get error 4.  Stop Process Monitor and look in log file for Access Denied errors and it will tell you exactly what location is failing on as well as the process / user that is trying to execute it.

Answer (score 3):

I've just managed to remove dotTrace altogether and just used an alternative, ANTS Profiler from Redgate.... too much hassle for me to investigate further as I'm basically on a time-constraint project.

Thanks everybody for the help!

Cheers,
A